# I want a c# IMAP client. Can I proceed with this new library?

Tags: c#, imap

Most of the recommended c# IMAP clients seem inactive. I came across [Equinox](http://equinox.codeplex.com/) IMAP library on codeplex. What pitfalls i should be aware of , if i choose to go with this new one?.

Comment: If you are ok using a commercial library, I can recommend you an excellent one..

Comment: Have you managed to make use of Equinox?

Comment: @aloneguid initially I made use of it and eventually had some problem with parsing and I changed to Lumisoft at that time. Equinox developer was quick to respond and he has helped a lot to improve. I think equinox has progressed well since then.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it still can't log in to GMail. I tried Lumisoft as well, but it fails on StoreMessage call with weirdo "+ +" exception. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suhair, as a commercial library I strongly recommend [MailBee.NET](http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/imap-component). I have used it in a commercial application and has been running successfully in a production environment for a while now.